# PHP function or file to run before and after every request

Tags: php, hook, execution

I am wondering if there is a way to specify a php function or file to be called every time a user visits and exits a page on my site. So if a user visits say example.com/ex.php can I have a function called before ex.php is run and after ex.php is finished?

I want to be able to record the time it takes to execute php files on my site and store that so I can run queries later to analyze the info. I would prefer not to have to add code to the beginning and end of every file I want to track.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested to see what approaches will be recommended. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try auto Append/prepend file ini directive.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 0):

Apache can log the time taken to serve a request directly. This includes more than just the PHP but may be better depending on your needs.

See [`mod_log_config docs`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html)